# UITextView not allowing text entry

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am completely confused. I have a view that has a `UITextView` called **slider1CommentsAFI** that will not allow me to enter text into it. When clicked it opens up and all the settings appear to be exactly the same as other `UItextViews` that work in the same way on the same view. In debug I get the following:

```
(lldb) print slider1CommentsAFI.editable
(BOOL) $0 = YES
(lldb) print slider1CommentsAFI.userInteractionEnabled
(BOOL) $1 = YES
```

and yet when you type nothing appears. Does anyone have any ideas what I can check? Below is a screen shot of the UITextView. Two open and one is fine but the lower simply does not allow anything to be entered. When I click inside it the `textViewDidBeginEditing` method is invoked, the cursor flashes but no typing allowed.

[image]

The code that opens the two UITextViews is below. The top UITextView is tag 2 and lower tag 8.

```
else if (obsComment.tag == 2 || obsComment.tag == 8)
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
slider1Comments.editable=YES;
slider1Comments.frame=CGRectMake(191, 135, 700, 230);
slider1Comments.backgroundColor= [UIColor whiteColor];
slider1Comments.textColor= [UIColor blackColor];
slider1CommentsAFI.editable=YES;
slider1CommentsAFI.frame=CGRectMake(191, 385, 700, 230);
slider1CommentsAFI.backgroundColor= [UIColor whiteColor];
slider1CommentsAFI.textColor= [UIColor blackColor];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Is it being loaded from a nib, or generated in code.  Either way some code or a screenshot would be helpful

Comment: It was created on the storyboard and then managed by code. Is that what you mean?

Comment: if your textview is added as a subview of a editable= NO superview it will not work. (not sure). other reason is you have another textfield or textview that is still being first responder even if the keyboard is not displayed anymore and the other textview or textfield is not visible

Comment: Could you post the controller code

Comment: @user3477129 I have added the textViewDidBeginEditing that opens the UITextViews. Maybe it is not possible to have two open at the same time?